# SQL Xml parsing nodes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml-parsing, nodes

I have a bit of XML with the following kind of format:

```
<Data>
  <Surveys>
    <Survey id="1">
       <Answers>
         <Answer aid="1">
         <Answer aid="2">
       </Answers>
    </Survey>
    <Survey id="2">
       <Answers>
         <Answer aid="1">
         <Answer aid="2">
         <Answer aid="3">
         <Answer aid="4">
       </Answers>
    </Survey>
  </Surveys>
</Data>
```

I'm inserting into a table for surveys like so (I've made this simple so not to have too much to deal with)

```
insert into survey
select T.o.value('@id', 'int'),
from @xml.nodes('/Data/Surveys/Survey')as T(o)
```

This is working... but I want to put in the associated answers to the surveys at the same point into a different related table.  I can't make a separate insert stmt and use the nodes again since the survey id is not in the answer nodes themselves.  In C# I can do this with LINQtoXML, but it's slower parsing/looping the elements.

Is there a way to do this in TSQL?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select T.o.value('@id', 'int') sid,
       A.o.value('@aid', 'int') as aid 
from @xml.nodes('/Data/Surveys/Survey')as T(o)
  cross apply T.o.nodes('Answers/Answer') as A(o)
```